# Sentence structure (use of colors)

Tags: grammar

1. I will use colors blue, red, and yellow.
2. I will use blue, red, and yellow colors.

Do these sentences make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 requires a definite article:

> I will use **the** colors blue, red and yellow.

Sentence 2 is grammatically correct.  It means you will use many shades of those colors.